# Error at the end of page (XML SVG) & CSS not working

Tags: css, xml, svg

This is my code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 22.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 
6.00 Build 0)  -->

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
width="385px" height="85px"
viewBox="0 0 143 32" 
enable-background="new 0 0 143 32" xml:space="preserve">


<style type="text/css"><![CDATA[

@keyframes leftGradient {
    0% { stop-color: rgb(255,255,255); }
        3% { stop-color: rgb(234,255,255); }
        4% { stop-color: rgb(234,255,255); }
        5% { stop-color: rgb(198,255,255); }
        10% { stop-color: rgb(10,255,255); }
        15% { stop-color: rgb(10,117,231); }
        20% { stop-color: rgb(58,126,192); }
        25% { stop-color: rgb(97,197,191); }
        30% { stop-color: rgb(0,150,128); }
        35% { stop-color: rgb(108,130,69); }
        40% { stop-color: rgb(6,219,40); }
        45% { stop-color: rgb(205,219,40); }
        50% { stop-color: rgb(255,199,8); }
        55% { stop-color: rgb(243,124,32); }
        60% { stop-color: rgb(236,30,36); }
        65% { stop-color: rgb(184,32,37); }
        70% { stop-color: rgb(84,1,37); }
        75% { stop-color: rgb(138,24,125); }
        80% { stop-color: rgb(212,24,194); }
        85% { stop-color: rgb(251,125,238); }
        95% { stop-color: rgb(247,203,242); }
        100% { stop-color: rgb(255,255,255); }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes leftGradient {
    0% { stop-color: rgb(255,255,255); }
        3% { stop-color: rgb(234,255,255); }
        4% { stop-color: rgb(234,255,255); }
        5% { stop-color: rgb(198,255,255); }
        10% { stop-color: rgb(10,255,255); }
        15% { stop-color: rgb(10,117,231); }
        20% { stop-color: rgb(58,126,192); }
        25% { stop-color: rgb(97,197,191); }
        30% { stop-color: rgb(0,150,128); }
        35% { stop-color: rgb(108,130,69); }
        40% { stop-color: rgb(6,219,40); }
        45% { stop-color: rgb(205,219,40); }
        50% { stop-color: rgb(255,199,8); }
        55% { stop-color: rgb(243,124,32); }
        60% { stop-color: rgb(236,30,36); }
        65% { stop-color: rgb(184,32,37); }
        70% { stop-color: rgb(84,1,37); }
        75% { stop-color: rgb(138,24,125); }
        80% { stop-color: rgb(212,24,194); }
        85% { stop-color: rgb(251,125,238); }
        95% { stop-color: rgb(247,203,242); }
        100% { stop-color: rgb(255,255,255); }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes leftGradient {
        0% { stop-color: rgb(255,255,255); }
        3% { stop-color: rgb(234,255,255); }
        4% { stop-color: rgb(234,255,255); }
        5% { stop-color: rgb(198,255,255); }
        10% { stop-color: rgb(10,255,255); }
        15% { stop-color: rgb(10,117,231); }
        20% { stop-color: rgb(58,126,192); }
        25% { stop-color: rgb(97,197,191); }
        30% { stop-color: rgb(0,150,128); }
        35% { stop-color: rgb(108,130,69); }
        40% { stop-color: rgb(6,219,40); }
        45% { stop-color: rgb(205,219,40); }
        50% { stop-color: rgb(255,199,8); }
        55% { stop-color: rgb(243,124,32); }
        60% { stop-color: rgb(236,30,36); }
        65% { stop-color: rgb(184,32,37); }
        70% { stop-color: rgb(84,1,37); }
        75% { stop-color: rgb(138,24,125); }
        80% { stop-color: rgb(212,24,194); }
        85% { stop-color: rgb(251,125,238); }
        95% { stop-color: rgb(247,203,242); }
        100% { stop-color: rgb(255,255,255); }
    }
    @keyframes rightGradient {
        0% { stop-color: rgb(255,255,255); }
        7% { stop-color: rgb(234,255,255); }
        14% { stop-color: rgb(234,255,255); }
        20% { stop-color: rgb(198,255,255); }
        24% { stop-color: rgb(10,255,255); }
        30% { stop-color: rgb(10,117,231); }
        36% { stop-color: rgb(58,126,192); }
        42% { stop-color: rgb(97,197,191); }
        48% { stop-color: rgb(0,150,128); }
        54% { stop-color: rgb(108,130,69); }
        60% { stop-color: rgb(205,219,40); }
        66% { stop-color: rgb(255,199,8); }
        72% { stop-color: rgb(236,30,36); }
        78% { stop-color: rgb(184,32,37); }
        84% { stop-color: rgb(243,124,32); }
        90% { stop-color: rgb(159,53,147); }
        100% { stop-color: rgb(255,255,255); }

    }
    @-webkit-keyframes rightGradient {
    0% { stop-color: rgb(255,255,255); }
        7% { stop-color: rgb(234,255,255); }
        14% { stop-color: rgb(234,255,255); }
        20% { stop-color: rgb(198,255,255); }
        24% { stop-color: rgb(10,255,255); }
        30% { stop-color: rgb(10,117,231); }
        36% { stop-color: rgb(58,126,192); }
        42% { stop-color: rgb(97,197,191); }
        48% { stop-color: rgb(0,150,128); }
        54% { stop-color: rgb(108,130,69); }
        60% { stop-color: rgb(205,219,40); }
        66% { stop-color: rgb(255,199,8); }
        72% { stop-color: rgb(236,30,36); }
        78% { stop-color: rgb(184,32,37); }
        84% { stop-color: rgb(243,124,32); }
        90% { stop-color: rgb(159,53,147); }
        100% { stop-color: rgb(255,255,255); }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes rightGradient {
        0% { stop-color: rgb(255,255,255); }
        7% { stop-color: rgb(234,255,255); }
        14% { stop-color: rgb(234,255,255); }
        20% { stop-color: rgb(198,255,255); }
        24% { stop-color: rgb(10,255,255); }
        30% { stop-color: rgb(10,117,231); }
        36% { stop-color: rgb(58,126,192); }
        42% { stop-color: rgb(97,197,191); }
        48% { stop-color: rgb(0,150,128); }
        54% { stop-color: rgb(108,130,69); }
        60% { stop-color: rgb(205,219,40); }
        66% { stop-color: rgb(255,199,8); }
        72% { stop-color: rgb(236,30,36); }
        78% { stop-color: rgb(184,32,37); }
        84% { stop-color: rgb(243,124,32); }
        90% { stop-color: rgb(159,53,147); }
        100% { stop-color: rgb(255,255,255); }
    }
#left { -webkit-animation: leftGradient 30s infinite; animation: leftGradient 30s infinite; }
#right { -webkit-animation: rightGradient 30s infinite; animation: rightGradient 30s infinite; }

    ]]></style>


<defs>  
    <linearGradient id="logo-gradient" x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%" > 

        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#7A5FFF">
            <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#7A5FFF; #01FF89; #7A5FFF" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
        </stop>

        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#01FF89">
            <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#01FF89; #7A5FFF; #01FF89" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
        </stop>

    </linearGradient> 
    <rect id="logo-gradient" x="0" y="100" width="100%" height="100%" style="fill:url(#mastGradient)" />
</defs>


<path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" opacity="1.00" d=" M 353.36 5.51 C 353.61 3.74 354.25 2.14 356.09 1.51 C 357.18 12.63 355.43 23.76 355.07 34.87 C 358.09 31.03 361.21 27.11 365.20 24.24 C 367.11 23.09 369.33 24.85 368.97 26.97 C 369.09 31.68 364.19 33.78 360.45 35.07 C 362.73 40.82 366.59 45.77 368.81 51.56 C 366.89 51.48 364.97 51.53 363.08 51.23 C 359.18 47.08 357.98 41.26 355.67 36.20 C 354.99 38.10 354.38 40.03 353.80 41.97 C 353.01 42.00 351.41 42.06 350.61 42.09 C 348.91 29.87 350.94 17.49 353.36 5.51 M 358.31 32.90 C 362.12 31.49 365.65 28.74 366.50 24.56 C 363.12 26.62 360.49 29.64 358.31 32.90 Z" />

<path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" opacity="1.00" d=" M 103.52 10.26 C 103.93 7.56 104.16 4.70 105.83 2.41 C 109.11 3.21 109.21 6.21 109.09 9.02 C 112.61 8.14 116.16 7.16 119.80 7.11 C 121.17 7.81 122.09 9.10 123.18 10.14 C 118.56 11.54 113.78 12.27 108.99 12.73 C 109.16 24.65 109.12 36.64 110.82 48.47 C 110.90 50.01 111.93 51.16 113.03 52.15 C 110.96 52.05 108.88 52.02 106.81 52.05 C 104.26 49.71 104.27 46.08 103.86 42.90 C 103.36 37.88 102.89 32.85 102.54 27.80 C 97.71 30.01 93.02 32.53 88.50 35.32 C 90.38 38.65 93.13 42.94 90.83 46.71 C 87.95 51.16 81.15 49.52 78.56 45.65 C 77.13 41.05 80.98 37.20 83.71 34.01 C 82.08 31.17 78.86 28.08 80.48 24.56 C 81.59 21.87 84.56 20.31 87.29 21.63 C 84.38 24.47 83.42 28.79 85.79 32.29 C 91.14 29.11 96.81 26.47 102.69 24.42 C 102.72 20.73 102.95 17.03 103.24 13.35 C 97.21 13.95 91.27 15.20 85.26 15.92 C 90.76 12.50 97.48 12.28 103.52 10.26 M 85.76 37.80 C 83.37 40.29 81.67 43.42 81.75 46.97 C 85.56 45.48 86.55 41.47 85.76 37.80 Z" />
<path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" opacity="1.00" d=" M 231.43 16.54 C 232.35 11.64 232.93 6.60 234.83 1.95 C 235.85 3.11 236.65 4.52 236.65 6.10 C 237.31 19.40 234.96 32.92 237.76 46.06 C 235.78 45.50 233.41 45.62 231.81 44.17 C 229.21 35.21 229.75 25.64 231.43 16.54 Z" />

<path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" opacity="1.00" d=" M 9.00 34.00 C 9.19 24.52 9.86 15.03 10.86 5.60 C 13.23 5.13 16.28 6.73 16.35 9.39 C 16.95 15.22 16.68 21.11 17.07 26.96 C 19.22 20.59 20.92 13.72 25.49 8.56 C 28.10 5.83 32.40 8.89 32.93 11.99 C 33.91 16.85 33.15 21.97 31.80 26.70 C 29.91 32.71 22.60 33.23 17.36 34.27 C 16.71 38.23 16.41 42.22 16.15 46.22 C 14.45 45.90 12.53 46.01 11.04 44.99 C 9.11 41.71 9.06 37.71 9.00 34.00 M 18.78 29.90 C 20.90 28.78 23.39 27.78 24.45 25.44 C 26.91 20.49 28.04 14.95 28.46 9.47 C 21.90 14.00 20.73 22.74 18.78 29.90 Z" />

<path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" opacity="1.00" d=" M 198.08 10.42 C 205.30 11.00 212.35 7.03 219.53 8.54 C 213.50 9.18 207.46 9.91 201.58 11.44 C 202.00 14.65 202.26 17.87 202.41 21.10 C 206.06 20.46 210.17 18.04 213.39 21.09 C 209.89 22.64 206.19 23.62 202.48 24.50 C 202.92 31.93 202.87 39.40 202.36 46.83 C 200.72 45.94 197.62 46.32 197.19 44.05 C 196.42 37.72 197.00 31.32 196.52 24.96 C 197.30 20.15 197.40 15.25 198.08 10.42 Z" />

<path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" opacity="1.00" d=" M 216.32 17.02 C 217.65 15.03 218.54 11.38 221.74 12.86 C 220.79 14.54 219.82 16.21 218.85 17.88 C 218.22 17.67 216.95 17.24 216.32 17.02 Z" />

<path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" opacity="1.00" d=" M 380.38 17.14 C 381.58 15.06 382.47 11.54 385.72 12.68 C 384.79 14.42 383.85 16.15 382.87 17.86 C 382.25 17.68 381.00 17.32 380.38 17.14 Z" />

<path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" opacity="1.00" d=" M 125.24 21.38 C 128.11 19.97 130.56 22.78 132.34 24.66 C 136.02 28.16 133.88 33.89 131.59 37.57 C 128.64 43.49 118.37 39.03 119.02 32.97 C 119.44 28.59 121.32 23.73 125.24 21.38 M 126.01 38.10 C 130.71 34.95 132.45 28.34 128.84 23.67 C 126.32 27.97 124.82 33.14 126.01 38.10 Z" />

<path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" opacity="1.00" d=" M 43.33 22.29 C 44.43 21.63 45.58 22.76 46.67 22.97 C 46.95 26.43 47.17 29.89 47.36 33.35 C 49.82 28.79 53.15 23.00 58.92 22.72 C 55.98 25.12 52.65 27.30 50.79 30.73 C 48.35 34.83 47.41 39.57 46.93 44.26 C 45.06 43.60 42.66 43.42 41.53 41.55 C 40.52 38.89 41.10 36.00 41.27 33.25 L 41.18 33.07 C 41.81 29.47 41.88 25.69 43.33 22.29 Z" />

<path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" opacity="1.00" d=" M 60.22 31.90 C 59.47 27.85 61.23 22.05 65.95 21.47 C 68.00 21.53 70.88 22.66 70.89 25.10 C 71.16 28.29 68.21 30.27 66.22 32.26 C 66.76 35.41 69.27 37.51 71.09 39.93 C 66.95 38.33 61.95 36.37 60.22 31.90 M 68.56 23.06 C 66.94 25.61 66.16 28.54 66.12 31.55 C 68.78 29.57 70.92 26.17 68.56 23.06 Z" />

<path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" opacity="1.00" d=" M 429.27 22.96 C 431.27 22.07 433.41 21.46 435.62 21.83 C 435.38 22.33 434.90 23.33 434.66 23.83 C 437.01 25.39 440.48 26.66 440.78 29.90 C 440.31 35.21 436.00 39.32 431.40 41.50 C 428.04 43.13 427.12 47.05 424.86 49.72 C 422.85 46.45 425.24 43.47 427.28 41.05 C 425.10 39.61 421.80 38.15 422.22 34.98 C 422.36 30.02 426.45 26.59 429.27 22.96 M 427.47 38.79 C 430.93 36.78 434.36 33.97 435.39 29.92 C 435.81 28.03 435.89 25.01 433.12 25.47 C 429.54 28.86 427.16 33.80 427.47 38.79 Z" />

<path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" opacity="1.00" d=" M 145.94 24.09 C 146.32 22.18 149.28 23.21 148.60 25.03 C 148.62 28.26 148.33 31.47 148.25 34.70 C 151.95 30.88 154.96 26.41 158.96 22.90 C 160.95 23.14 162.36 25.08 162.32 27.03 C 163.09 34.31 162.39 41.66 163.15 48.95 C 161.10 47.95 158.92 47.19 157.04 45.89 C 155.06 39.33 156.98 32.40 157.85 25.82 C 154.65 29.31 152.79 33.73 149.84 37.39 C 147.45 38.06 144.28 36.74 144.12 34.01 C 143.98 30.63 144.61 27.20 145.94 24.09 Z" />

<path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" opacity="1.00" d=" M 215.90 22.34 C 217.18 22.64 218.46 22.96 219.75 23.28 C 219.16 30.41 219.55 37.55 219.98 44.67 C 218.38 44.33 216.78 43.99 215.19 43.62 C 214.24 36.60 212.77 29.04 215.90 22.34 Z" />

<path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" opacity="1.00" d=" M 335.20 24.38 C 336.64 21.84 340.75 23.27 340.80 25.99 C 341.38 31.09 340.95 36.27 339.98 41.30 C 338.11 40.37 335.81 39.83 334.48 38.13 C 334.31 35.92 334.49 33.70 334.57 31.48 C 333.34 32.95 332.19 34.50 330.74 35.76 C 328.29 36.60 324.97 35.55 324.03 32.99 C 323.55 29.09 326.21 25.12 329.99 24.07 C 331.72 23.82 333.47 24.22 335.20 24.38 M 328.96 33.10 C 331.36 30.88 333.51 28.39 335.19 25.58 C 331.90 26.82 330.24 30.06 328.96 33.10 Z" />

<path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" opacity="1.00" d=" M 379.92 22.33 C 381.19 22.63 382.46 22.94 383.73 23.26 C 383.18 30.39 383.54 37.54 383.98 44.67 C 382.37 44.34 380.78 43.99 379.19 43.63 C 378.24 36.61 376.75 29.02 379.92 22.33 Z" />

<path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" opacity="1.00" d=" M 395.29 23.35 C 395.71 23.27 396.56 23.12 396.98 23.04 C 398.40 26.70 397.03 30.85 397.25 34.70 C 400.92 30.69 404.31 26.44 408.07 22.52 C 409.16 23.56 411.01 24.26 411.15 25.97 C 412.23 33.59 411.32 41.31 412.14 48.95 C 410.10 47.95 407.91 47.19 406.04 45.88 C 404.07 39.33 405.97 32.40 406.85 25.83 C 403.73 29.48 401.44 33.71 398.84 37.72 C 396.79 37.36 393.96 37.28 393.28 34.84 C 392.73 30.95 393.64 26.89 395.29 23.35 Z" />

<path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" opacity="1.00" d=" M 248.82 23.96 C 249.51 24.00 250.87 24.10 251.55 24.14 C 251.71 28.58 251.74 33.02 252.14 37.45 C 254.65 34.31 256.35 30.61 259.05 27.62 C 259.54 27.61 260.51 27.58 260.99 27.56 C 262.17 29.92 262.46 32.57 262.96 35.12 C 265.09 32.25 267.05 29.04 270.13 27.07 C 272.13 26.68 274.51 27.98 274.93 30.07 C 276.32 35.65 276.19 41.51 275.83 47.22 C 274.06 46.85 271.92 47.03 270.56 45.64 C 269.14 40.30 270.02 34.78 270.59 29.39 C 267.17 32.97 264.81 37.43 263.48 42.18 C 261.83 41.86 260.19 41.51 258.56 41.14 C 258.29 37.05 258.45 32.96 258.77 28.88 C 256.55 33.17 255.26 37.93 252.48 41.93 C 250.96 41.22 249.12 41.03 247.88 39.84 C 246.06 34.68 247.28 29.03 248.82 23.96 Z" />

<path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" opacity="1.00" d=" M 286.82 23.95 C 287.51 24.00 288.87 24.10 289.56 24.15 C 289.71 28.59 289.74 33.03 290.14 37.45 C 293.03 34.18 294.36 29.48 298.17 27.13 C 300.54 29.04 300.22 32.43 300.96 35.12 C 303.09 32.25 305.05 29.03 308.14 27.08 C 310.13 26.68 312.51 27.98 312.93 30.07 C 314.33 35.65 314.18 41.51 313.83 47.22 C 312.06 46.86 309.97 47.01 308.57 45.68 C 307.14 40.32 308.01 34.79 308.59 29.39 C 305.17 32.98 302.82 37.43 301.47 42.18 C 299.83 41.87 298.19 41.52 296.57 41.15 C 296.28 37.11 296.43 33.06 296.80 29.04 C 294.47 33.23 293.24 37.96 290.49 41.93 C 288.98 41.21 287.10 41.04 285.87 39.82 C 284.06 34.67 285.29 29.02 286.82 23.95 Z" />

<path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" opacity="1.00" d=" M 438.22 43.26 C 440.47 42.31 442.38 44.39 444.29 45.25 C 441.13 47.56 437.74 49.51 434.51 51.73 C 437.84 57.96 430.75 63.97 425.04 64.78 C 422.14 64.50 417.46 62.95 418.32 59.17 C 419.70 55.24 422.95 52.26 426.47 50.21 C 426.70 49.87 427.16 49.20 427.39 48.87 C 431.27 47.53 434.37 44.64 438.22 43.26 M 423.93 61.80 C 428.23 60.31 432.33 57.25 433.50 52.63 C 429.67 54.93 426.20 57.92 423.93 61.80 Z" />
```

This was working as an HTML file. I recreated this SVG in Illustrator and copied the elements from HTML and applied to this SVG and added the fills to the path, following tutorials online.

can anyone help me with this? please.

1. I keep getting the error 'at the end of the document' - it had  at the end, I deleted that but threw the same error but with a different number. I deleted empty spaces but that too threw the same error with another number.
2. I have no idea why the CSS isn't being picked up, it's working well in my HTML file - Nothing has been removed or changed.

Thanks

Comment: where is the closing `</svg>` tag?

Comment: It said that was an error, so I removed it.

Comment: Strange now its working! but my text is cut. Still no idea why the CSS in't working

Answer (score 0):

> Strange now its working! but my text is cut.

The reason your text is cut off is because your `viewBox` is too small.
Try changing it to:

```
viewBox="0 0 445 65"
```

> Still no idea why the CSS in't working

Your CSS does nothing because it isn't targeting any elements in your file.

Your CSS targets elements with `id="left"` and `id="right"`. But there aren't any elements in your SVG with those ids.